# How do I pass array items in an component and return it inside of another component

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass array items using .map to the specials component.

I have been at this for days now I just really want to get passed this already. Every time I render and upload to the browser it keeps giving me the error of

> "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."

```
import React from "react";

export const SpecialButton = (props) => {
  const { special }  = props
  return (
    <>
      {<button>{ special }</button>}
    </>
  );
};
```

Special file

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

//import any components needed
import { SpecialButton } from "./SpecialButton"
//Import your array data to from the provided data file
import { specials } from "../../../data"

export const Specials = () => {
  // STEP 2 - add the imported data to state

  const [specialState,setSpecials] = useState(specials)


  return (
    <div>
       {specialState.map(i => <SpecialButton special={i} />)}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Specials
```

data file

```
export const specials = ["C", "+/-", "%"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add key parameter as below.

```
{specialState.map((item, index) => <SpecialButton special={item} key={index} />)}
```

Comment: Additionally, `index` as a key is not a good idea. You should use something unique from your array.

Comment: @ravibagul91 I absolutely agree with you, but It will be okay in that simple component. And there will not be any conflicts with other keys.

Answer (score 0):

> "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."

This message comes for dynamically created elements when the key property is not set, ex: from loops, maps, etc.

React uses the key property to track elements that are rendered, therefore its important to set a unique key to all the children inside a certain parent.

```
{ specialState.map((item) => <SpecialButton special={item} key={item} />) }
```

I have set the key as the item since your data array seems to have unique values.

The reason why i have not used the index as the key can be found here:
https://medium.com/@vraa/why-using-an-index-as-key-in-react-is-probably-a-bad-idea-7543de68b17c

Answer (score 0):

I already have the same problem even if I set key in parent of the fragment. In my case, I simply replace the `<>` / `</>` with `<React.Fragment key={SOME_KEY}>` / `</React.Fragment>`.

I hope it can help you.